# Server Tomcat v7.0 at localhost failed to start

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, localhost

I have been working on Eclipse IDE and Tomcat v7.0. Till yesterday it was working fine. Even the jsp files were executing fine so no error in code. Earlier when I got error like this, I changed port numbers, clean server and project it worked. But this time I tried the following using these forums

1) I tried everything on Google.

2) Changed port numbers.

3) Changed server location.

4) Deleted .snap file in directory.

5) Reinstalled tomcat multiple times.

6) Cleaned project and server.

7) Changed the version of tomcat but it didn't detect.

I tried changing the properties and everything. It says `no tcnative-1 in library path` so I re-installed the whole thing thrice. I don't know what else to do. Have to submit the project in 3 weeks and I'm stuck.

Can anyone please tell me what else to do?

Web.xml file 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHC3o.png

Catalina log file at 17.14

```
15-Nov-2019 17:14:27.676 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.27
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Oct 7 2019 09:57:22 UTC
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.27.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.004 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: abort
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.23] using APR version [1.7.0].
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
15-Nov-2019 17:14:28.379 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:29.910 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:46.926 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:51.176 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8018"]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:51.285 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [39,257] milliseconds
15-Nov-2019 17:14:53.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:53.238 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
15-Nov-2019 17:14:59.939 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [com.sathish.booking.controller.BookingServlet] and [com.sathish.flight.controller.FlightServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/flight] which is not permitted
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:342)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2459)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2135)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2016)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1142)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.017 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [com.sathish.booking.controller.BookingServlet] and [com.sathish.flight.controller.FlightServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/flight] which is not permitted
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:342)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2459)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2135)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2016)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1142)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.017 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/airlines]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [com.sathish.booking.controller.BookingServlet] and [com.sathish.flight.controller.FlightServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/flight] which is not permitted
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:342)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2459)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClass(ContextConfig.java:2135)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2124)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2016)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:2010)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processClasses(ContextConfig.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1142)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 27 more
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.033 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.033 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8018"]
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.033 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina] 
Nov-2019 17:15:00.033 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
15-Nov-2019 17:15:00.049 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8018"]![web.xml file] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHC3o.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPOT9.png)
```

Comment: anything in the tomcat logs ?

Comment: What should I check in the logs folder??

Comment: usually catalina.log or catalina.date.log give the startup failure reason

Comment: This is what it says. The error which occurred at 17:15 https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ANcq4LVtYlaHbfhi6X7NbGJEbLw2LQe/view

Comment: I don't have access. Please copy/paste as text by editing your question.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: And I also uninstalled tomcat v7 and tried with v9

Comment: Configuration error ? The log says `The servlets named [com.sathish.booking.controller.BookingServlet] and [com.sathish.flight.controller.FlightServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/flight] which is not permitted`

Comment: This is how my web.xml looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHC3o.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your stack trace states that :

> The servlets named [com.sathish.booking.controller.BookingServlet] and
>   [com.sathish.flight.controller.FlightServlet] are both mapped to the
>   url-pattern [/flight] which is not permitted

Your servlet-mapping configuration (it may be in the web.xml, it depends on your application type) contains two servlets that are mapped to the same url.
I suppose that you should change the servlet mapping of the bookingServlet to use the /booking url.

Comment: How do I do that? This is how my web.xml looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHC3o.png